# Limit execute time for oci_execute in PHP

Tags: php, oracle, settimeout, connection-timeout

everyone
I have a function called oci_execute to get data from the oracle store procedure.
I want to set time out of oci_execute because sometimes the oracle server is slow & stuck.
Code:

```
function callOcl() {
  try{
    ...
    oci_execute(...);
    ...
  } catch (\Exception $ex) {
    // exception message...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is probably achievable by using the [oci_set_call_timeout](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-set-call-timout.php) function.

According to the documentation:

> Sets a timeout limiting the maximum time a database round-trip using this connection may take.

You can set it after initialising your connection and it will apply to any subsequent call to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I also used this but when the remote server of oracle is unreachable it's stuck in the oci_connect() line.